# c# net Error trying to inherit from GridView

Tags: c#, inheritance, gridview

Error trying to inherit from GridView, what can i do? I added reference to:
System.Web, as suggested in another post.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace fsdb_UI
{
    public class slGrd : GridView
    {

    }

}`
```

Comment: `GridView` is in the namespace `System.Web.UI.WebControls` so you should use `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` or `public class slGrd : WebControls.GridView` since you are already referencing `System.Web.UI`.

Comment: what do you mean by *"I added reference"* ? How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

was missing a reference to assembly system.web. Problem solved